# intelij IDEA "new directory" not showing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory

So as the title describes my really basic question for intelij IDEA.
When I want to create a new folder/directory in the structure window, it doesn't show the option in the dropdown when I right click and go to "New".
Any idea what the problem is?
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its called Package in intellij. Outside of java (the `package` keyword),  package, folder, and directory all mean the same thing. A place to hold other packages/folders/directories/ and files in.

Edit: intellij also uses Directory. (it seems by default) Although i'm guessing you were creating a package/folder/directory already somewhere inside of a directory named *java*. Inside here it will be called Package.